# Adjust width of input field to modal

Tags: javascript

I have a modal defined with an input box on it. The modal scales to the size of the browser window.

However, the existing code allows the input window to be wider than the modal window.

I've tried setting the input width but it looks like it's set in characters.  So while I can reduce it in size with JavaScript, it doesn't really work well.

```
    <body onresize="myFunction()">
    <body onload="myFunction()">

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <input id="AAAA" placeholder="Enter email address"></input>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {

    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var xx = (w-100);

    document.getElementById("AAAA").width = xx;
    //  document.getElementById("AAAA").size = (w-75)/8;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It 'kind of' works, but not really.

I want to input field to be centered, and with a slight distance on each side (that is, a fixed size smaller then the window) but for it to otherwise expand out to the size of the window.

Comment: Hello @J., could you add the css styles of the input and its modal parent? Maybe we can solve it just with css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give another try with css:

> However, the existing code allows the input window to be wider than the modal window.

- Probably, the input has a width based on [`vw`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), that refers to the % of the width of the viewport.

> I want to input field to be centered, and with a slight distance on each side (that is, a fixed size smaller then the window) but for it to otherwise expand out to the size of the window.

- Try: `#AAA { width: 90%; margin: auto; }`.
- Also check if it contains a `min-width` or`max-width` that interferes with the styles.
- And remember to check the width of the input-s parent (probably the modal wrapper). Take into account that `#AAA` will have the `width: 90%;` of its element.

Hope it helps.